# How is $O(cn \log_{3/2}n) = O(n \lg{n})$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I am reading Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition and it says that $O(cn \log_{3/2}n) = O(n \lg{n})$. But isn't $\lg{x}$ tighter than $\log_{3/2}x$?

Comment: Are you okay with the constant $c$ present in the $LHS$ vanishing on the $RHS$ of the equation?

Comment: Obviously, it's big-oh notation so it doesn't matter anyway. I copied the equation from the book as it is.

Comment: Oh, alright. Then I guess the answers below help you out. At first, I thought that you weren't familiar with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant) rule, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\text{log}_{2}(n) = \dfrac{\log_{3}(n)}{\log_{3}(2)}$, per the change of base formula. The $\log_{3}(2)$ term is absorbed by the constant factor, which you have from the definition of Big-O.

Comment: So, this means that the base of the logarithm doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Correct. If the author includes an explicit base in the logarithm, it is usually to prod the reader to fill in a detail in the proof (e.g., $\log_{2}$ might prod you to consider a binary recursion tree or the evaluation of binary strings). However, the base has no bearing on the asymptotics.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\log_{3/2}n=\ln n/\ln(3/2)$.